# How to use xstring IfEq inside command?

Tags: xstring

I wrote a command for accessing a hardcoded string ("For Reasons™", because xstring `StrMid` is incredibly slow on large strings) and wonder now

- Why can the results be printed but not reused?
- How would I write this command so that it can be further used?

This snippet runs as expected and generates the following pdf.

```
  debug for part two
  \newcounter{debugctr}
  \setcounter{debugctr}{-1}
    {\loop
    \stepcounter{debugctr}
    \edef\tmpinput{\the\numexpr \value{debugctr} - 0}
    \def\tmpchar{\expandafter\lucidcharat\tmpinput}
    (\tmpinput)[\tmpchar],
    %\edef\tmpcharr{\tmpchar}
    \show\tmpchar
    %\typeout{tmpchar is \tmpchar}
    \ifnum \value{debugctr}<3
    \repeat }
```

[image]

The command `lucidcharat`  is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\lucidcharat}[1]{
\edef\tmpp{#1}
\IfEq{\tmpp}{0}{1}{}%
\IfEq{\tmpp}{1}{2}{}%
\IfEq{\tmpp}{2}{2}{}%
}
```

and is input to the other file with `\input{sneakycode}`.

I assume this all has to do with how fickle `xstring` is with regard to evaluation. To demonstrate what I mean with "results can not be further used" uncomment one of the commented lines above and you'll see that neither `typeout` nor `edef` work. They'll error out with

```
!  Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@a ->\def \xs@dessep
{,}\@xs@readdecimalpart
l.617 \repeat
```

Please help me understand how a command using `IfEq`  internally would be written so that it can be reused e.g. for comparison of the output and why it is not working currently.

Here's the complete MCVE for copy-pasting again (It's the same as above, just put together into one file):

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\lucidcharat}[1]{
\edef\tmpp{#1}
\IfEq{\tmpp}{0}{1}{}%
\IfEq{\tmpp}{1}{2}{}%
\IfEq{\tmpp}{2}{2}{}%
}

\begin{document}
  debug for part two
  \newcounter{debugctr}
  \setcounter{debugctr}{-1}
    {\loop
    \stepcounter{debugctr}
    \edef\tmpinput{\the\numexpr \value{debugctr} - 0}
    \def\tmpchar{\expandafter\lucidcharat\tmpinput}
    (\tmpinput)[\tmpchar],
    %\edef\tmpcharr{\tmpchar}
    \show\tmpchar
    %\typeout{tmpchar is \tmpchar}
    \ifnum \value{debugctr}<3
    \repeat }
\end{document}
```

Comment: please post your code in a form that allows people to run it and debug the issue, but note that unrelated to xstring you can not use fragile commands (anything using assignments internally) in edef  typeout and similar contexts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Re your second comment: The argument is something that should evaluate to a number (a counter, a literal numeric character, the result of a numexpr, ...). You can see that in the first code snippet. But I don't think that `edef` is my problem? I mean, the command evaluates correctly when writing the result to the PDF

Comment: I don't know what answer you want other than `\lucidacharat` is a fragile command (because of the def that you do and xstring does)  so can not be used in a `\typeout` unless prefixed by `\protect` when it will just print as itself. You can probably do expandable tests instead of using xstring but you have not said what test you are intending.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm looking for an explanation why that does not work. (I have to retract my previous statement that `edef`  is not my problem. Using `ifnum` instead of `IfEq`  does not help.) I guess it boils down to me not understanding fragility. Why is the def a problem?

Comment: because  in an edef (or a write) assignments do not happen, just expansion, so if you expand  `\def\foo{}` then `\def` stays as the token `\def` and `\foo`  gives an undefined command error as you are expanding it when it is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what is your intended output, but as you need it to work in an edef, you need expandable tests, this uses `\ifcase` to test for the argument being 0 1 or 2 and outputs 1 2 2 respectively.

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\newcommand{\lucidcharat}[1]{%
\ifcase\numexpr#1\relax
1\or2\or2\else\fi}

\begin{document}
  debug for part two
  \newcounter{debugctr}
  \setcounter{debugctr}{-1}
    {\loop
    \stepcounter{debugctr}%
    \edef\tmpinput{\the\numexpr \value{debugctr} - 0}%
    \def\tmpchar{\expandafter\lucidcharat\tmpinput}%
    (\tmpinput)[\tmpchar],
    \edef\tmpcharr{\tmpchar}%
    \show\tmpcharr
    \typeout{tmpchar is \tmpchar}%
    \ifnum \value{debugctr}<3
    \repeat }
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping to do. But I'm still wondering why the `edef`  in the command definition posed a problem. I don't have any `def` inside the argument to `lucidcharat`, have I? Because that's how I understand your comment above - that I cannot `\edef\tempp{#1}` when `#1`  contains a `\def`

Comment: yes but you can't have lucidacharat in an edef for the same reason it expanded to an edef. @lucidbrot

Comment: if you put lucidacharat in an edef (with any argument) after one expansion you had `\edef\tmpp{...}` then `\edef` expands to itself, and `\tmpp` gives a command not defined error. @lucidbrot

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks! Why is  the inner `edef` not be evaluated including its argument though?

Comment: @lucidbrot because that's what happens in an edef or write, only expansion, no assignments

Comment: because it's in an edef